# How to solve type must have a symbol iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm new to TypeScript and i'm trying to set some state in my react Context. In this case it should be a simple number which you can change with the "setTotal" state function.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};

interface IThemeContext {
  total: number;
  setTotal: () => void;
}

export const TotalContext = React.createContext<IThemeContext>(0);

export function TotalComponent({ children }: Props) {
  const [total, setTotal] = useContext(TotalContext);
  return (
    <TotalContext.Provider value={[total, setTotal]}>
      <>{children}</>;
    </TotalContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TotalComponent;
```

I'm getting the following error: IThemeContext' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks!